# ASP.NET Identity saves user data to old membership tables

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-membership, asp.net-identity

I created a new ASP .NET MVC 5 project as well as I created ASP .NET Identity tables.

But somehow some AspNet tables appeared and when I register new user it keeps all user data under the old tables.

Is that correct? Should not it save under new tables like Users?

What do I am missing?

[image]

P.S. That MS link does not help understand that  behavior http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Google I found answer I need here

http://www.itorian.com/2013/11/customize-users-profile-in-aspnet.html

It seems like I am facing two sets of tables because of the 
Simple Membership and ASP.NET Identity System are presented at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Those tables created are done by the IdentityDbContext. In the OnModelCreating method of the IdentityDbContext the tables are assigned the names you have highlighted in your screenshot like so.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");
```

If you would like to rename them, you would have to override the OnModelCreating method in your own implementation and name them as you would like.

Comment: I see. But why do we have two sets of the tables? Could u explain it please?

Comment: I see you answered this yourself.